# multiple casting rule C++

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code,

```
    std::transform (source.begin(), source.end(),  // start and end of source 
            dest.begin(),                  // start of destination 
            (int(*)(int const&)) addValue<int,5>);  // operation
```

Can somebody break down the cast,

```
    (int(*)(int const&))
```

where addValue is Nontype Function Template give as

```
    template <typename T, int VAL> 
    T addValue (T const& x) 
    { 
        return x + VAL; 
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast `(int(*)(int const&))` is a cast to the type `int(*)(int const&)`, which is the type "pointer to function taking `int const&` and returning `int`".

Since `addValue<int, 5>` already has the type "function taking `int const&` and returning `int`" (and will decay to function pointer when passed by value), the cast is unnecessary in this context.

An example of when such a cast would be useful would be to disambiguate between multiple function templates with the same name. If, in addition to the `addValue` definition shown, we had this also:

```
template <typename T, int VAL>
void addValue(T& x) {
    x += VAL;
}
```

then specifying `addValue<int, 5>` alone would be ambiguous. Telling the compiler what type `addValue` is supposed to have after instantiation would tell it to use `int addValue<int, 5>(int const&)` instead of `void addValue<int, 5>(int&)`, so it would know which template to pick.